# How to access an Universal Worklist with mobile Devices?

Tags: java, mobile, netweaver, webdynpro

first some context for the problem:

we are using **SAP NetWeaver Developer Studio** to create business processes. Creating User Interfaces with **Web Dynpro Java**.

A process will be controlled by the universal worklist (UWL) which can be accessed by its API as far as I know.

My **Question** is: *Can anyone give me a hint how to access an UWL or parts of a process in a UWL via mobile devices?* Any Experience with it? The first application is a process that got an approval step somewhere close to the end. For this approval a Web Dynpro application exists, but the approver should also be able to use his/her mobile device to approve something within an mobile app or something.

We would love to see that HTML5 is *the One*, but if there is a way using NetWeaver Developer Studio or even Web Dynpro for it that's quite cool, too.

If there is something we can use for our UWL that works for all devices and can be used by other SAP or non-SAP Applications too, that might even be the best solution.

I hope I explained everything sufficiently, thanks for reading.

Greetings

Gian-Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are now using SAP Gateway and Sybase SUP to get this issue done. Let's see how this works out.